# Pushing to gcr.io from gitlab-ci, storage.buckets.get permission in storage admin

Tags: python, docker, gitlab, google-cloud-storage, gitlab-ci

I am putting together a gitlab CI pipeline for building, testing, pushing and deploying react app.

Everythings for fine now, except pushing images to GCR.

This is my the part of the pipeline:

```
image: docker:stable

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - push-artifacts
  - deploy-dev
  - deploy-prod

services:
  - docker:dind

...

publish: 
  stage: push-artifacts

  script:
    - echo "$GCLOUD_SERVICE_KEY" | base64 -d > /gcloud-service-key.json
    - cat /gcloud-service-key.json | docker login -u _json_key --password-stdin https://$IMAGE_ROOT
    - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO:$CI_BUILD_REF -f builder/Dockerfile -t $IMAGE_REPO:latest .
    - docker push $IMAGE_REPO
```

I am using gitlab-ci service account which has both Storage Admin and Storage Object Admin IAMs.

I am using dind and docker-builder. Here is my builder dockerfile

```
FROM docker:stable

# add dependencies
RUN apk add --update make ca-certificates openssl python curl bash tree git jq && \
    update-ca-certificates

WORKDIR /
RUN cd / && wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
    tar zxvf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
    ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false --path-update=true

# add gcloud to PATH
ENV PATH="/google-cloud-sdk/bin/:${PATH}"

# update and auth
RUN gcloud --quiet components update && \
    gcloud components install kubectl 

# install helm
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/helm/master/scripts/get | bash
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/gcloud-service-key.json 
RUN helm init --client-only && helm plugin install https://github.com/nouney/helm-gcs
```

The react Dockerfile is just a regular reactapp dockerfile with `serve` as command. But the push part is still failing

```
Successfully built bd60c4bb569e
Successfully tagged eu.gcr.io/project_name/app:46d1e4beea041acef9ca003f452ee4cbda85d5dd
Successfully tagged eu.gcr.io/project_name/app:latest
$ docker push $IMAGE_REPO
The push refers to repository [eu.gcr.io/project_name/app]
11762a30dfcd: Preparing
f475c6042475: Preparing
526599eebb83: Preparing
c328c8c7f46b: Preparing
71d6c8e5f47f: Preparing
48b131779e9d: Preparing
4b2ccfc1ebff: Preparing
2f810bf9ddab: Preparing
968d46c1d20e: Preparing
b87598efb2f0: Preparing
f1b5933fe4b5: Preparing
48b131779e9d: Waiting
4b2ccfc1ebff: Waiting
2f810bf9ddab: Waiting
968d46c1d20e: Waiting
b87598efb2f0: Waiting
f1b5933fe4b5: Waiting
denied: Token exchange failed for project 'project_name'. Caller does not have permission 'storage.buckets.get'. To configure permissions, follow instructions at: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control
```

Login is successful but still permission issues. Why?

My base64 encoded service token json key is in gitlab environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using a Service account or user account (owner of gcloud-service-key.json) for access to your project but you need to add storage admin role to your account, check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-roles-to-service-accounts#granting_access_to_a_service_account_for_a_resource) as a reference for granting roles.

Comment: The service account is editor of the entire project + storage admin

Comment: Is the name of your project "project_name" is correct?

Comment: Yes. Checked infinite times

Comment: according to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#pushing_an_image_to_a_registry) you need to use the project id instead the name of your project for example:

docker push eu.gcr.io/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]

Answer (score 0):

It missing the Storage write scope, If you want to use the docker command line, another solution is to use the gcloud command line, yo already authenticate to SDK, then you have just do the gcloud command to push :

```
gcloud docker -- push $IMAGE_REPO
```